# Price display and Price Update with HTML Input Checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to build a web app where when a user checks off a box, the price updates. Example: Base price is $3, user Checks box and it becomes $5, checks box 2 & 3 it becomes $10, etc. How do I build the javascript code for this? Here is my code below.

```
<label for="bathroomcleaning">Bathroom: </label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox"> Clean bowl and wipe down toilet cover, seat, under seat, base and behind the base.
<br>
<input type="checkbox"> Clean all mirrors.
<br>
<input type="checkbox"> Clean countertops and backsplashes.
```

I wrote this,

```
function display() 
{ 
    var x = document.getElementById("myCheck").value; 
}
```

but I haven't figure out a way to display the value attribute of the checkbox. I figure, to make it easier, see if I could first display the value of the checkbox, then figure out how to add them however I've gotten no luck.

Comment: function display() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myCheck").value;
   
}
I've wrote this, but I haven't figure out a way to display the value attribute of the checkbox. I figure, to make it easier, see if I could first display the value of the checkbox, then figure out how to add them however I've gotten no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I modified your HTML with IDs:

```
<label for="bathroomcleaning">Bathroom: </label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="box-1"> Clean bowl and wipe down toilet cover, seat, under seat, base and behind the base.
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="box-2"> Clean all mirrors.
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="box-3"> Clean countertops and backsplashes.
```

Then I made a new `<label>` to display the price:

```
<label for="bathroomprice" id="price">Price: </label>
```

Then I added a `<script>` tag and a JavaScript script inside it:

```
<script>

    function checkPrice() {
        var price = 3;
        if (document.getElementById("box-1").checked == true) {
            price = 5;
        }

        if (document.getElementById("box-2").checked == true && document.getElementById("box-3").checked == true) {
            price = 10;
        }

        document.getElementById("price").innerText = "Price: " + price;
    }

</script>
```

Finally, I added an `onclick` event to all the `<input>`s that checks the price whenever you click an `<input>`:

```
<label for="bathroomcleaning">Bathroom: </label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="box-1" onclick="checkPrice()"> Clean bowl and wipe down toilet cover, seat, under seat, base and behind the base.
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="box-2" onclick="checkPrice()"> Clean all mirrors.
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="box-3" onclick="checkPrice()"> Clean countertops and backsplashes.
```

Here's the finished product:

```html
<label for="bathroomcleaning">Bathroom: </label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="box-1" onclick="checkPrice()"> Clean bowl and wipe down toilet cover, seat, under seat, base and behind the base.
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="box-2" onclick="checkPrice()"> Clean all mirrors.
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="box-3" onclick="checkPrice()"> Clean countertops and backsplashes.
<br>
<label for="bathroomprice" id="price">Price: </label>

<script>

    function checkPrice() {
        var price = 3;
        if (document.getElementById("box-1").checked == true) {
            price = 5;
        }
    
        if (document.getElementById("box-2").checked == true && document.getElementById("box-3").checked == true) {
            price = 10;
        }
    
        document.getElementById("price").innerText = "Price: " + price;
    }

</script>
```